# strange results when plotting a function that i declared

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I've declared two functions, the first of which (Gamma) works fine, but the second gives me really strange results that aren't right (after checking in excel). I've tried changing al the parameters but nothing seems to work, here is the code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={gamma(\z)=
    (2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z) + 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5) + 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5) - (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920 - (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z);},
    declare function={digamma(\x)=
      (ln(gamma( \x+0.001)) -   ln(gamma( \x-0.001))/ (0.002) )   ;}

]

\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    samples=100,
]
\addplot [smooth, domain=0:20] {digamma(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the output:
[image]

and based on excel, this is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Did you plot the digamma function in excel or your approximation thereof?

Comment: Note also that you've plotted them on very different domains.  Start by making the domains the same and add samples=200 in the addplot options.

Comment: @JPi I plotted my approximation in excel. why are the domains so different? in the code its 0:20, in excel i graphed it in increments of0.01 from 0 to 7. increasing the samples changes the shape slightly but still very different to the excel version